# CefSharp windows7 eror

Tags: c#, cefsharp

when I open an app containing CefSharp 65.0 it  doesn't work and I face CLR20r3
stopped working Eror. machine's OS is Windows 7
I already installed vc2012 & vc2013 
any idea?

Comment: Did u install `VC++` .? also please go through the document [GitHub](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/NuGet/Readme.txt#L18) if in case , you missed something out.

Comment: As per the release notes version `65` requires `VC++2015` see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v65.0.0

Comment: It worked Thanks @amaitland